# How to update the screen once it has lost focus

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm working on a program that requires WM_ERASEBKGND to be disabled (to avoid flickering).

The problem comes in when my main window loses focus,  and another window (another program) gains the focus.

The window that has the focus (not my program) invalidates MY program's window every time it passes over it! The result is, my window's screen turns white everywhere that another window has passed by it, leaving it almost totally blank afterward. Obviously, I cannot have a program where the screen turns white every time it loses focus.

Is there any way to continue my window's drawing operations, (continue calling wm_paint, for example) even after my window has lost focus (WM_KILLFOCUS)?

Comment: You should continue getting WM_PAINT messages even after losing the focus. The trick with WM_ERASEBKGND is that your WM_PAINT should cover all the pixels of the window. Are you sure you implemented WM_PAINT that way?

Comment: I thought returning a value of "true" to WM_ERASEBKGND stops all calls to WM_PAINT after the screen has been invalidated (which would mean that I'd have to implement manual calls to WM_PAINT via SendMessage(); As things are now, WM_PAINT is somehow not being called when WM_ERASEBKGND is disabled.

Comment: @JamesDiaz: returning true for `WM_ERASEBKGND` simply tells Windows that you drew your own background so a default background will not be drawn. That has no effect on how `WM_PAINT` behaves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, from the comments above, **never** send the `WM_PAINT` manually with `SendMessage` or `PostMessage`. Use `InvalidateRect` to instruct the window to be repainted.

About the `WM_ERASEBKGND`, the return value is used to indicate the `WM_PAINT` handler that the background has been erased, in case the paint procedure can be optimized. To actually prevent the background from being erased, simply do not call `DefWndProc()` for that message. Or even easier, set the `hbrBackground` to `NULL` in the window class.

As others mentioned the focus has nothing to do with repainting, and your window should paint normally even while in the background.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your answer totally lead me in the right direction, awesome.